# How do I run a VBA function in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I want to run [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086270/how-to-extract-text-within-a-string-of-text)

I opened the developer tab in excel, no clue what to do now. I tried creating a "macro button", and then paste the function code in the macro script, but if I press play I get a error related to `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`

and if i try to save the macro, I get this dialog box:

[image]

Comment: The error dialog tells you exactly what's going on, and what you need to do.  So where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: I clicked yes, it didn't chang anything. I even don't care about saving this, I just want to run it, no clue how to do that.

Comment: Like the error says, you need to use a macro-enabled workbook (.XLSM) for macros to work...  Beyond that "I get a error related to Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()" doesn't tell us enough, we need to know exactly what the error said.

Comment: The SE question you refer to has specific instructions how to call this function. I don't believe simply running it will work. It is looking for variables which are given when it is called.

Answer (score -1):

#### Saving Excel files with Functions / macros:

In your message prompt shown in your question, Click `No` - Excel will take you to the `Save As` dialog. Enter the file name and remember to select the file type as `Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook` and click `Save`.

#### Running the function:

You have to select any cell (in any of the worksheet within the same file) and type the name of the function `=RegexExtract()` ( with any of the applicable arguments) to see the function work.